# Port not showing for Forwarding on VSCode for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]I want to forward port on but can't see the PORT on the command line bar. how do I fix this.

I tried restarting the vscode but still did not work. I also checked if there's extension for it and also checked the web version of vscode but could not see the port to forward, does this has to do with mac or the vscode version. kindly